# Is ranging over an array a bad way to write a simple loop?

Tags: loops, go

I sometimes tire of writing the ForClause `for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {` loop for a constant number of loops where the loop iterator isn't needed. I sometimes wish I could use range and an integer like `for range 7 {` but that is invalid. I have found you can use `for range [7]int{} {`.

Which seems fine:

```golang
package kata

import (
    "runtime"
    "testing"
)

const times = 100_000

func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("For", func(b *testing.B) {
        for j := 0; j < b.N; j++ {
            for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
                runtime.Gosched()
            }
        }
    })
    b.Run("Range", func(b *testing.B) {
        for j := 0; j < b.N; j++ {
            for range [times]int{} {
                runtime.Gosched()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```
% go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/brackendawson/kata
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkLoop/For-12                 157           8963540 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop/Range-12               162           7651102 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      github.com/brackendawson/kata    4.695s
```

Is this safe? Am I pointlessly saving 4 keystrokes? I feel dirty.

Comment: Check out https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bradfitz/iter instead; but, if you do use Brad's trick, copy his code, don't depend on it.

Comment: It works, and you can see from the benchmark the compiler manages to optimize away the allocation. IMHO you should be optimizing for the reader of your code (which may be you, later), not the writer, and "tricks" like this just increase the overhead of reading the code.

Comment: While it does work, characters are cheap. Especially if your editor has a "fori" macro (like GoLand). What is expensive, is the time of developers who may be slowed down trying to comprehend your quirky code.

Comment: I agree with you all on the readability. I think I was coming from a place where I thought `for range 7 {` would be readable, and then thinking I could replicate that. But this approach is just 10 seconds wasted every time a reader has to comprehend it.

Comment: Optimise for reading, not for writing; also, [clear is better than clever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=14m34s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While safe, I would argue this is not idiomatic. In Go, strive for the simplest code possible. The original `for` loop is much clearer for readers, and code should be optimized for reading, not for saving keystrokes (for saving keystrokes, consider configuring your editor/IDE instead?)

If you insist on making it shorter, at least use something like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bradfitz/iter (or reimplement it - it's trivial), to be able to write:

```
for i := range iter.N(10) {
    // ....
}
```

This is shorter and is more readable than having that array there explicitly, though I'd still argue it's *less* readable than a vanilla `for` loop.

---

To conclude, just don't :-)

Answer (score -1):

Personally I do use this idiom now and then, although I use a `struct` instead:

```
package main

func main() {
   for range [9]struct{}{} {
      println("hey homie")
   }
}
```

as empty struct takes zero bytes. I don't think it's that different from Python `range` [1]:

```
for _ in range(9):
   print('hey homie')
```

1. https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-range